# Removing an hour from PHP (FROM_UNIXTIME)

Tags: php, gmt, unix-timestamp

Could you please advice how to remove an hour from unixtime.

I have a unixtime and i need to remove an extra hour before converting to normal time. Could you please advice how to do this?

Also, is Unixtime affected by the GMT time changes?

Comment: How about `$timestamp - (60 * 60)`?

Comment: @netcoder you mean `$timestamp - 3600` :)?

Comment: @webarto: Yes. It's just that I don't like magic numbers. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unix timestamps are measured in seconds, there are 3600 seconds in an hour (60 minutes, each with 60 seconds = 60*60 = 3600), so just subtract:

```
$timestamp = time();
$timestamp_less_one_hour = $timestamp - 3600;
```

You can also use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) to accomplish the same:

```
$timestamp_less_one_hour = strtotime('-1 hour', $timestamp);
```

Or if `$timestamp` is simply "now" you can call `strtotime` without the second parameter:

```
$timestamp_less_one_hour = strtotime('-1 hour'); // time() - 1 hour
```

---

So you seem to be looking for GMT time instead, the trouble is GMT can include Daylight Savings Time (DST), and the "GMT" date functions in PHP actually return UTC time, which has no concept of DST.  Luckily you can detect if it's DST using PHP, and basically adjust appropriately.

Get UTC time using [`gmdate`](http://php.net/gmdate):

```
$utc_time = gmdate('U'); // return Unix seconds in UTC timezone
```

Detect if it's DST using `I`:

```
$is_dst = gmdate('I'); // 1 when it's DST, 0 otherwise
```

`gmdate('U')` will trail GMT time during DST by an hour, thus you need to give it `+3600` seconds, or 1 hour when it's DST, so putting this together:

```
$gmt_time = gmdate('U') + (3600*gmdate('I'));
```

Comment: `strtotime('-1 hour', $timestamp);`, he already has timestamp ;)

Comment: I was like, he is pretty fast :)

Comment: Thanks guys :) - You have any idea how to turn UNIXTIME to GMT? My code died and I just figured that I was using UNIXTIME. So it stores the time an hour before. Please help or direct me where I can find help. :-)

Comment: @Buki: "UNIXTIME" doesn't have a known timezone, it's based on your server's configuration. Are you pulling the time from a database or asking PHP for it?

Comment: @Buki use [`gmdate`](http://php.net/gmdate) to just return unixtime in seconds in the GMT timezone as: `$timestamp = gmdate('U');`

Comment: @Mark Elliot : I have done that and it didnt work. The UK time moved forward one hour. It's still showing the time -1. An option is to + 3600 but does that mean I have to keep updating the code for every time change (i.e. when it changes again to -1)?

Comment: @Buki: okay, so there's some fine points about `gmdate` and Daylight Savings Time, check my edit.

Comment: @Mark Elliot: Thanks Mark, but it's still returning a false time. The time is 02:27 but it returns 01:27. This is what I echoed: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $gmt_time);`

Comment: @Buki: what does `gmdate('I')` return for you?

Comment: @Mark Elliot: It returns: `0`

Comment: @Buki: My test here gives the right time even though DST isn't flagged as on: http://ideone.com/vjFKe; is the time on your server wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, i'm using an external software. Is there any way of checking?

Comment: @Buki: can you tell me the results of both `gmdate('c')` and `date('c')`?

Comment: @Mark Elliot: `gmdate('c')` returns: `2011-04-06T01:44:15+00:00` AND `date('c')` returns `2011-04-06T01:44:15+00:00`. The same thing.

Comment: @Buki: so the server time is set incorrectly, not much you can do about that but manually add an hour to correct for DST.

Comment: Ah. I have to contact my Server company then. I guess I would need to change the code every time there is a time change. Thanks for your help Mark. You rule!! :-)